# DCOS Cassandra - Run cassandraDemon with non-root user

Tags: cassandra-2.1, dcos

I want to run cassandraDemon in dcos with non-root user. Like during cassandra instalation on dcos ,I  wnat to change the service.user to . 
How can we do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user `core` exists on the Agents, you would do it like this:

```
$ cat options.json
{
  "service": {
    "user": "core"
  }
}

$ dcos package install --options=options.json cassandra
DC/OS Cassandra Service default configuration requires 3 nodes each with 1.5 CPU shares, 5376MB of memory and 11264MB of disk for running Cassandra Nodes. And, 1 node with 0.5 CPU shares, 2048MB of     memory for running the service scheduler.
Continue installing? [yes/no] yes
Installing Marathon app for package [cassandra] version [1.0.25-3.0.10]
Installing CLI subcommand for package [cassandra] version [1.0.25-3.0.10]
New command available: dcos cassandra
DC/OS Apache Cassandra has been successfully installed!

    Documentation: https://docs.mesosphere.com/current/usage/service-guides/cassandra/
    Issues: https://dcosjira.atlassian.net/projects/CASSANDRA/issues
```